# How to shift $y=-\ln(-x)$ so that the $x$ intercept is $0$ instead of $-1$?

Tags: calculus

I would like this function shifted to the right. I'm not quite sure how.  As positive values of $x$ grow, I need increasing slope.

Answer (score 2):

These two rules are good to know ($f$ is the original function, $g$ is the shifted one):

- To shift $f(x)$ **up** by $c$ units, let $g(x) = f(x) + c$
- To shift $f(x)$ **to the right** by $c$ units, let $g(x) = f(x-c)$.

In your situation, $f = -\ln(-x)$.

---

**Aside:** Note that your (shifted) function is not defined (in the real number system) for values of $x\ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

The same function shifted $-a$ units to the right would be: $g(x)=-\ln(x-a)$.

We need to solve the following equation:

$-\ln(-0-a)=0 \Leftrightarrow \ln(-a)=0 \Rightarrow -a=1 \Rightarrow a=-1$.

In this case, the original function should be shifted $1$ unit to the right.

Answer (score 0):

To shift the graph 1 unit to the right, replace $x$ by $x-1$ to get
$y=-\ln(-(x-1))$,

which simplifies to $y=-\ln(1-x)$.